# Sigma and Series involving factorials

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone please try this problem? It is kinda complex as it has factorial in the sigma and I could not see any telescopic addition possible here.
Find the Sum given below:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{16n^2 +20n +7}{(4n+2)!} $

Comment: Is your goal to evaluate the sum or just determine if it converges?

Comment: According to [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) the closed form for this sum is a sum of 3 hypergeometric functions, so OP probably just wants a convergence result.

Comment: I want to compute the sum. It converges.

Answer (score 6):

Please note that $$16n^2+20n+7=(4n+2)(4n+1)+2(4n+2)+1$$

So,
$$\frac{16n^2 +20n +7}{(4n+2)!}=\frac{1}{(4n)!}+\frac{2}{(4n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(4n+2)!}$$$$=\frac{1}{(4n)!}+\frac{1}{(4n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(4n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(4n+3)!}+\left(\frac{1}{(4n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(4n+3)!}\right)$$

Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{16n^2 +20n +7}{(4n+2)!}=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{n!}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}-+\ldots \right)$$
$$=e+\sin1$$

Comment: Maple gets
$$
\frac72\,
{\mbox{$_2$F$_5$}\left({\frac{13}{8}}-\frac{i}{8}\sqrt {3},
{\frac{13}{8}}+\frac{i}{8}\sqrt {3};\,\frac34,\frac54,\frac32,\frac58-\frac{i}{8}\sqrt {3},
\frac58+\frac{i}{8}\sqrt {3};\,{\frac{1}{256}}\right)}
$$
which agrees with $e+\sin 1$ to (at least) $50$ decimals.

Comment: Maple I didn't quite understand your solution. Thanks though. Pls elaborate.